# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: newSession

Tags: selenium, firefox, capybara, geckodriver

I am running my rspec test with selenium webdriver. The setup looks the following way:

```
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.app = Rack::File.new File.expand_path('../fixtures', __FILE__)

require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  options.args << '--headless' if travis?

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: options)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :firefox
```

When I run `rspec` the tests fail with

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/select2-v3/index.html'

 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   newSession
 # WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5
 # UnknownCommandError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:472:5
 # despatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:290:13
 # execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:271:11
 # onPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:246:15
 # onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:245:8
 # _onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9
 # ./spec/select2_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Googling around didn't give me any results.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

**Update:** I am using firefox v63.0

Comment: Have same issue after firefox update to version 63.0. The firefox version 60.0 is all good.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest version of `geckodriver` (v0.23.0) to work with Firefox 63.

Comment: On mac, I had to run `brew upgrade geckodriver`

Comment: If the upgrade command doesn't work it's probably because Firefox installed it rather than Homebrew, in which case you have to `brew install geckodriver` instead, and make sure to overwrite the symlink (Homebrew will warn you and show you how), otherwise the system will continue to use the old version of geckodriver. Hope this helps!

Comment: @KristophMatthews The easiest solution is to just add the `webdrivers` gem to your project and let it handle managing geckodriver.

Answer (score 0):

I did 
`brew install geckodriver` then tried `brew link geckodriver` then an error message says the target file directory already exist. So I removed the target file directory using 
`rm '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'` before linking again using `brew link geckodriver`